# Setting a shortcut to split the current screen in half using screen.area_split

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut, operator, keymap

I'm trying to set a key bind to activate the `screen.area_split` so that I don't have to use the mouse, and instead splits the screen 50/50 down the middle. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two [`Operators`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html) for splitting area horizontally and another one for splitting area vertically with the following script. Copy and paste this in the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) under the *Scripting Tab* and click *Run Script* button to generate these operators.

```
import bpy

class SplitAreaHorizontalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "screen.splitarea_horizontal_operator"
    bl_label = "Split Area Horizontal Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='HORIZONTAL', factor=0.5)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SplitAreaHorizontalOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SplitAreaHorizontalOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    #bpy.ops.screen.splitarea_horizontal_operator()

class SplitAreaVerticalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "screen.splitarea_vertical_operator"
    bl_label = "Split Area Vertical Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.5)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SplitAreaVerticalOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SplitAreaVerticalOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    #bpy.ops.screen.splitarea_vertical_operator()
```

Check by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> anywhere and type/search *split area* to see if they have been registered. Then test them if they work properly.

[image]

You can do a keybind via script as [explained in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271204/keybinding-for-a-python-script) but I'm going to add them manually under *Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Screen* and then expand *Screen (Global)*.

[image]

At the bottom of the key binding list, add your key binding to the list and search for the operator `screen.splitarea_horizontal_operator`.

In this example, I added and configured a keybinding of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for splitting horizontally. Add another one for the vertical split operator `screen.splitarea_vertical_operator`.

[image]